# ajax returns 401 with json, nodejs and webpack

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, webpack

I'm building a web app with the adobe analytics API and everything works fine locally. when i deployed to a server the fetch for the locally stored json (i.e. stored on the same server as the app) returns a status code 401. I've double checked the file path and it is correct.

I don't want to use webpack's json-loader because that will parse the json at compile-time and the json file being loaded will differ depending on what the user does at run-time.

any help / suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: **401** stands for "Unauthorized" [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error).

Comment: any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You are asking for authentication and your script does not provide it?

Comment: yea im using Nginx Basic Authentication but i didnt think it would interfere once authenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%C3%81lvaro-gonz%C3%A1lez) mentioned, my script did not provide support for the authentication that I set up. Using ES6's fetch I was retrieving a JSON file from the same source as the app and needed to provide the current user's login credentials for NGINX's basic_auth. As I did not implement authentication on my local machine I did not run into this problem until I deployed my app. the solution:

```js
fetch("src/json/" + data, {
  "credentials": "same-origin"
})
```